# Set default font with package Fontawesome

Tags: fonts, fontawesome

Recently I asked how is it possible to add some logo (skype, linkedin, Facebook, ) to my CV with the package font awesome. Thanks to people here who provided me a great answer. However, I noticed that the font was changed for the whole document.

That's a pity for me because I really like the default font and I would like to use for all the document. Thus, how can I set the default font to the following code?

```
% PACKAGES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.6cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,25,80}


% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{blue}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}


% Title line color


% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 96pt

% Computer skills 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\grade}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (1em-.3em,-.3em) rectangle (5em +.5em ,.3em);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (1em-.3em,-.3em) rectangle (#1em +.5em ,.3em);
            \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
                \path[fill=blue] (\x em,0) circle (.27em);
            }
        \end{scope}
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
            \draw[color=blue] (\x em,0) circle (.27em);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}



\usepackage{fontspec}%<added
\usepackage{libertine}%<added


\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path=/Users/arnaudmonay/Desktop/AM_CV_UK/,Scale=.80]{FontAwesome.otf}
\def\fafacebooksq{{\FA \symbol{"F082}}}
\def\faphone{{\FA \symbol{"F095}}}
\def\faphonesq{{\FA \symbol{"F098}}}
\def\fatwitter{{\FA \symbol{"F099}}}
\def\fakeyboardo{{\FA \symbol{"F11C}}}





% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\leavevmode
\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
\ignorespaces}



\setlength\parindent{0pt}


% Personal informations and picture
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.7pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{cv_picture.jpg}}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\mymarginnote{\smash{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\textbf{Branch Warren}}}
\mbox{}

\mymarginnote{\faphonesq route 17 \\ aabama 76 \\ Switzerland \\ \faphone +4176 67 34 56 \\ branchwarren} 
Born on the 2th of March  1887

US nationality

\textcolor{red}{\fakeyboardo}~Branchwarren@gmail.com

\fatwitter~twitter

\fafacebooksq~facebook

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone who can help me

Comment: Please (1) minimise your code to what is actually required. (Is TikZ really needed?) (2) Tell us what you actually want. How can we guess what the font was before you made the changes, when we don't know what changes you made? You don't provide a link to the previous question. You don't tell us which font you want. And you don't tell us what you added, deleted or changed in response to that question. So... we are left wishing our crystal balls weren't still being repaired. (I must say, they are taking their time with them.)

Comment: Whay don't you use the fontawesome `package`?

Comment: Well, you have `\usepackage{libertine}` that makes Linux Libertine the main document font. Remove it.

Comment: @cfr: thanks for your comments. Next time I will try to provide a better example.
egreg: it was exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for this :):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the package `fontawesome` and run it with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. Do *not*  load package `inputenc` and *not* `fontenc` and use the already defined macros of `fontawesome`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.6cm, right=3.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}%<added
\usepackage{libertine}%<added
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}    
\marginnote{\faPhoneSquare route 17 \\ aabama 76 \\ Switzerland \\ \faPhone +4176 67 34 
    56 \\ branchwarren} 
    Born on the 2th of March  1887

    US nationality

    \textcolor{red}{\faKeyboardO}~Branchwarren@gmail.com

    \faTwitter~twitter

    \faFacebookSquare~facebook

\end{document}
```

[image]